# Grab all documents whose IDs are not present in a separate table

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a `users` table and a `tasks` table. In `tasks`, each document consists of a `user_id` field (which is an ID from the `users` table) and some other, irrelevant fields.

I would like to filter users after some criteria (`.filter({'field': 'value'})`), then get only those users that are **NOT** in the `tasks` table (that `user_id` field).

I started the query: `r.table('users').filter({'field': 'value'})` but I don't quite have a clue on how to write that "user shouldn't be found in `tasks` table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest ReQL expression (including querying another table inside a method (like `filter`).
You want to use some indexes here to make things faster.

```
r.table('tasks').createIndex('user_id').run()
r.table('users').filter(...).filter(function(user) {
    return r.table('users').getAll(user('id'), {index: 'user_id'}).isEmpty()
})
```